# implicit declaration of function 'ITM_SenderChar' is invalid in C99 issue in KEIL

Tags: arm, cortex-m, keil, firmware

I came across the warning message as follow from Keil's uVision at the cortex-m3's "HELLO" example.

warning: implicit declaration of function 'ITM_SenderChar' is invalid in C99

when I implement ITM_SendChar('\r');

what am I supposed to do to resolve this problem?

below is snippet code

```
int fputc(int c, FILE *f) {
  if (c == '\n')  {
    ITM_SendChar('\r'); //<== invalid?
  }
  return(ITM_SendChar(c)); 
}
```

update

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWCI9.jpg

you can see the warning message from above image.
and one more thing, If I click 'Goto the definition ITM_SenderChar' on pop-up menu, then

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9yGc.jpg

the browse window is appearing.

Comment: you didnt provide the declaration, the function prototype...is there none?  did you forget to include the header file?

Comment: @old_timer you are right. Thanks it is solved.

Answer (score 0):

As old_timer said, I resolve this issue by adding Core_cm3.h in "CMSDK_CM3.h".
this issue happens due to lack of declaration.